# Update google sheet without Oauth or API key

Tags: python, linux, shell, google-sheets

Basically I am looking for updating the google sheet from my linux/unix box using shell scripts. Since I couldnt find much with shell scripts , thought of using python to update the google sheet.
Most answers were redirecting to create google project for its api key / OAuth key.
 I could not create a project in google api / generate a api key as i dont have access to create one at organization level / no organization level. Its asking for location to choose and I dont find any.

Is there any other way to update a google sheet with wget or sudo or  CURL or any other method in python ?

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61484573

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need an organization to create an API Key, when you click on "New Project" in the Google Cloud Platform you can leave it blank.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7C2T.png

Then you have to use the api key in your python code to be able to access your sheets.

Comment: No , it asks for location to be browsed. And pops up "you do not have the required resourcemanager.projects.create permission to create a project"

Comment: are you using your personal google account? if you have another account try with it to check if the same behavior happens.

Comment: Using for a  buisness account , and due to security reasons couldnt able to create one :(

Comment: Well an idea could be to share your spreadsheet with account with full privilege and then using it for the python calls.

Comment: Sounds like a brilliant one , but how do we call from python with just gsheet shareable link ? Any example would be really helpful

Comment: For the required permissions error, did you create a [new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143060/you-do-not-have-permission-to-create-projects-in-this-location)?

Comment: @Jescanellas : In that case , am not admin to provide access for my organisation.